# Is there a word for 'love letter'?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

Some types of *letters* — i.e., messages that you write on a piece of paper and send to someone — have their own name.

In fact, for example, we call 'note' a short letter to someone, 'rejection' a letter that tells you that you did not get a job or were not accepted by a school, 'response' a reply to any question or letter, and so on.

Even a letter sent regularly to members of an organization, containing news, has a name, 'newsletter', which is, as in the cases already mentioned, a single word.

That being said, my question is, is there a single word which one can use to refer to a 'love letter' — i.e., 'a letter telling someone how much you love them'?

Comment: I believe that **is** called a *love letter*. [Many dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=love+letter&ls=a) give that two-word expression its own entry. I don't know why the blank space between the _ve_ and the _le_ is bothering you so much. (Also, I wouldn't call a letter that told me I wasn't accepted to a school a "rejection," I'd call the written note a "rejection letter," or I would say "I was rejected by the university." If someone told me they got a "rejection," that could be a phone call as easily as a letter.)

Comment: I found the word billet-doux, which is not technically one word or English for that matter, and it's not a particularly common word (I'd never heard it).

Comment: @J.R., don't you know that scientists have developed a new brain scanner which uses the entire English alphabet **and the blank space** to help paralysed people spell words using their thoughts? I think that almost no one can properly refute that the *blank space* is important. And, FWIW, I found the definition of 'rejection' in a dictionary, though.

Comment: Atsuto: Yes, spaces are important, but I am afraid you are missing my point. _Love letter_ is the best answer to your question. Related (and a very good read): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121860. And, FWIW, that definition of rejection may be in the dictionary ([Collins 6](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rejection), e.g.), but that doesn't refute the fact that _rejection letter_ is still a [commonly-used term](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=pp#hl=en&q=%22rejection+letter%22).

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo Please provide a link to the relevant dictionary entry.

Comment: @Trevor D, [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/american/Letters-and-types-of-letter).

Comment: @ J.R., sorry, I'm loking for a nice and non-conventional single word, which I would use in a new essay I'm writing and whose title I have already decided, "The Love Letter."

Comment: You now say *for the first time* that you are looking for a *non-conventional* word, by which I assume you mean a 'made-up' word. You also say that this is for *writing*, in which case you may be better asking this question at [writers.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a *non-conventional* word for use in writing an essay entitled "The Lover Letter". It is therefore better suited to [writers.se]

Comment: I think "non-conventional" here doesn't mean "made-up", but perhaps "unusual" or "novel" or "exotic" instead. I still don't see why it needs to be a single word, but, if the O.P. is worried about overusing _love letter_, there's also _love-note_, _letter of affection_, and maybe even _valentine_, although that last one would be a stretch.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question: see the tags. It may or may not have a perfectly fitting answer -- that doesn't disqualify the question in any way. *Rejection* is an example and is hardly relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

Wiktionary gives billet-doux, which is technically a borrowed word, but is used in the English language in the same manner as any borrowed term, such as crime passionnel.

The only alternative I can think of is the conditional term "Valentine" which can mean "An expression of affection, especially romantic affection, usually in the form of greeting card, gift, or message given to a person the object of affection, especially on February 14th.". While it is conditional, it is the only single word term for a love letter that I could find.

Otherwise it appears that there is no single word term.

As a last note, I would like to point out that the noun "rejection" is not commonly used to refer to a rejection letter; if you have heard it used as such, it was probably being used as a colloquialism or in a context where its meaning was obvious. For example a situation in which a person holding a letter states "It's a rejection". Even in that context, its usage would be uncommon, people almost always say "rejection letter" in full.

Comment: Also, http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/billet--doux?q=billet-doux and other sources.

Comment: Billet-doux is a nice word, yes, but it is virtually unknown.